# Fetch a data from database which is inserted in date time format but want to fetch only by date

Tags: php, mysql, date

Dates entered in database:

[image]

Like : January 19, 2012, 3:25 pm

But if want to search a registered name by only date, means i want to search only by the date, i want to input my date like this

```
January 19, 2012
```

Without the time... Any help here ??? Thankss ..

Comment: Try `DATE()` function.

Comment: i want to search by giving this date in the date picker.. so where should i put this 1 ??

Comment: you should have used datetime instead of varchar...

Comment: Its already done by some other developer .. & there is already more than 3000 entries are inserted in database.. so cant change that

Comment: No i dnt want to echo anything , i want to search only

Comment: i m not inputting anything.. Its an ongoing site with more than 3000 registration.. i m given the work to search by date

Comment: I mean how are getting the date to be searched.?

Comment: try STR_TO_DATE() http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: i want to get the date like this January 19, 2012 but in the database the dates are entered with time format  @웃웃웃웃웃

Comment: You column `date` is of which datatype: `varchar` or `datetime` ?

Comment: @sarmistha did you check my answer?

Comment: i ve commented there @rullof

Comment: @sarmistha you didnt mentioned what is the datatype?

Comment: Solved :) by @rullof ' answer .. thankss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [MySQL Regular Expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/regexp.html):

```
$date   = "January 19, 2012";
$query  = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date REGEXP '". $date. "'");
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

Comment: $n_rows = 0;
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $srQuery = $_REQUEST;
  $sbynm = mysql_escape_string(trim($srQuery['sbynm']));
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search_tbl WHERE date LIKE '%".$sbynm."%' AND v=1 AND d=0");
  $n_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
  $msgs = 'NF';

i m using this code , can u update ur code according to mine

Comment: What does `$srQuery['sbynm']` contain?

Comment: hey can u give me date picker which ll give me date exactly this format January 19, 2012

Comment: Any date picker works just some edit on the arrangment!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I know what it is you're asking for, but perhaps you can format either of the two dates to match one another. Or a better option would be to add or edit the structure of your database column.
Try a format approach using "strftime()" if you want to keep the same database layout.

```
<?php
    $date = 'datetimeFromDatabase';
    $compareTo = strftime('%B %d, %Y', $date);
    $compareWith = $_POST['userInput'];
?>
```

Comment: i cant change the database format as its already running with an ongoing site... i just want to search the registered name with dates like this January 19, 2012 but the date are inserted with times also

Comment: already solved.. Thanks for this also :) Happy new year

Answer (score 0):

First, convert date format as you want in PHP then same format in mysql

Like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DATE(datecolumns) = 'January 19, 2012'
```